# How to test for a partially mediated model?

Tags: least-squares, causality, mediation, dag, partial-effect

I have a dataset with three variables: Outcome, Exposure, and Mediator.

My hypothesis is that the variables are related as in the following DAG:

[image]

In particular I want to test that "Mediator" in effect partially mediate the relationship between Outcome and Exposure.

That is, Exposure causes Mediator and Mediator causes Outcome. But also, Exposure causes Outcome directly too.

How can I test whether Mediator is a partially mediate the relationship between Exposure and Outcome?

Comment: Why don't you compare the causal effect of Exposure on Outcome with no conditioning, with the causal effect of Exposure on Outcome while conditioning on the Mediator? If they're different, that would show that you have some significant causality going through the mediator. If they're not very different, then the mediator isn't doing a whole lot.

Comment: @AdrianKeister how to quantify "there are different" versus "they are not very different"?

Comment: And most importantly, how to test whether the difference in the coefficients is due only to random noise?

Comment: Well, how you quantify the difference is up to you. You could do percent difference, but there are other options. As for the random noise question, that's subtle. I think what you're asking is how much of the difference, if there is much, is due to the mediator itself, versus the always-implied endogenous variable $U_M$ with an arrow into the mediator (and nothing else). Does that sound right? It certainly would be the case that if you condition on the mediator, then no causal information can flow from $U_M$ to $I.$ And if you don't condition, causal information can flow.

Comment: Question: is this all in a linear regression setting? Or are you doing more general probabilities?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes it's linear regression

Comment: Regarding the literature on mediation, the question could be improved. What do you want to know exactly? How to test if there is a mediated effect? if the mediated effect is significant? if it is substantial (of practical importance)? or if is is partly mediated (like in the the Baron and Kenny framework of mediation (the later being somewhat "outdated"?

Comment: @POC all the first three questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, here are answers to the three question.

**How to test if there is a mediated effect?** There is many ways to test indirect, the recommended methods is the bootstrap methods. You can find some useful informations in this [paper](https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol14-2/p147/index.html). Mplus, R, SPSS (via process), SAS, MATLAB, etc. can all carry the analysis.

**If the mediated effect is significant?** Using the confidence interval computed via bootstrap you check if the indirect is significant. Is the interval holds 0, then, the null hypothesis of no indirect effect if not rejected. Otherwise, you can reject the null hypothesis.

**Is the indirect effect substantial (of practical importance)?** This is probably the hardest problem about indirect effects. There is no definitive effect size to directly compare to, like you would with cohen's $d$ or correlation coefficients $r$, or any others. Historically, some has used the Baron and Kenny method distinguishing fully vs partly mediated (see paper for details), but I would discourage it use. Some would use the proportion of mediated effect. But this effect size has more challenges than an actual answer in practices. I would recommend to use your own judgments as well as following the recommandation in your specific field.